# Incorrect path to SignalR generated on client

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

So I have been plugging away trying to get SignalR to work with my Web Api instance that used OWIN and authentication. After figuring out CORS (thanks to SO help) I am almost there.

My web client fails with a Javascript error on the console.

```
http://localhost:45325/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&_=1460577212205 404 (Not Found)
```

if I take this URL and put it in the browser sure enough I get a `404` error. However if I add `/signalr/` to the path as such ...

```
http://localhost:45325/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&_=1460577212205
```

I get a proper JSON response with the SignalR `connectionid` and everything ...

```
{
"Url": "/signalr",
"ConnectionToken": "<token here>",
"ConnectionId": "0bf84c7a-0a28-4da9-bb9f-551de894cf0e",
"KeepAliveTimeout": 20,
"DisconnectTimeout": 30,
"ConnectionTimeout": 110,
"TryWebSockets": true,
"ProtocolVersion": "1.5",
"TransportConnectTimeout": 5,
"LongPollDelay": 0
}
```

So it looks as though everything is working other than the fact that the URL the client is generating to connect to the SignalR hub is missing the `/signalr`.

Here is my client side Javascript that connects to the Hub. Where can I specify the path needs to include `/signalr`? Because I thought I already was ...

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var connection = $.hubConnection('/signalr/', {useDefaultPath: false});
        var myHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('MyHub');
        myHubProxy.on('notify', function (username) {
            console.log(username + ' has logged in');
            alert(username + ' has logged in');
        });

        connection.url = 'http://localhost:45325';

        connection.start()
            .done(function() {
                alert('Connected to MyHub: Connection ID = ' + connection.id);
            })
            .fail(function(e) {
                console.log('Connection error: ' + e);
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

You may notice that I did not include `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`. This is because I am created the proxy myself instead of relying on the auto-generated proxy

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! It should have been obvious to me ...

In my Javascript on the client I needed to add the `\signalr` path ...

```
connection.url = 'http://localhost:45325/signalr';
```

Perhaps I should have seen that in my `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder)` method inside the `Startup.cs` class of my Web Api I had the following ..

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
    {
        // EnableJSONP = true;  // I am not using as CORS is working just fine
    };
    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

I was specifying the subdirectory `"/signalr"`